# Digital Ocean & WordPress ftp write to wp-content directory?

Tags: wordpress, digital-ocean

I am experiencing challenges with a new WordPress installation on a Digital Ocean droplet. The Ubuntu server is running with Apache, PHP, MySQL and WorkPress. I then had to install an FTP daemon and so installed vsftpd. It is currently working without SSL.

I purchased a theme and am trying to upload it for installation. It now uploads and accepts the ftp user credentials that I setup. However I get an error ... "Installing Theme from uploaded file: themeforest-19744911-ultranet-broadband-internet-service-providers-wordpress-theme-wordpress-theme.zip Unable to locate WordPress content directory (wp-content)."

It appears that it wants to write the files to the /var/www/html/wp-content directory instead of the /home/user/ftp/files directory.

I can create a new user such as "wpuser" but how do I set the default ftp director to ".../wp-content". Finally would I have to remove the chroot jail as presumable these files will need to be read write?

Comment: Where did you install WordPress? There is no good reason that anything related to your web site should be in a user home directory. `/var/www/html/wp-content` looks correct; `/home/user/ftp/files` looks wrong.

Comment: Are you familiar with SSH by chance? I think you're complicating this a bit with whole FTP server setup. You can upload files using the SSH function called `scp` as long as you've access to the server with privilege user. It's all command-line but, much simpler than FTP.

Comment: Thank you. The theme pack installer asked for an ftp user and password, which surprised me as there was no ftp requirement detail in the set-up instructions supplied by Digital Ocean, which I have followed to the letter.

Comment: the /home/user/ftp/files is the default that vsftp application recommended. I too do not see how this could possibly help to install a theme pack to the /var/www/html/wp-content directory.